# Run a GET command via telnet in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal, http, telnet

I'm trying to run a `GET` command in Terminal in Mac OS X, and I get this far:

```
telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 2607:f8b0:4009:808::2004...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.google.com
```

But after that I'm not sure what to press to run the `GET`.  Pressing return just takes me to a new line and nothing seems to happen. Other key combinations don't seem to do anything useful either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing up this question, I somewhat arbitrarily discovered that hitting return twice gets the request to run.  It's just that simple.